# Conditional Formatting based on weeknumber

Tags: excel, excel-2010

Fellow Excel Enthusiasts,

I'm looking for a way to use conditional formatting to check if my invoice should be payed.
[image]

Added picture is how my data looks at this point in time. 
What I am trying to achieve, is that when in column J the value (=weeknumber based on 25 days after date in column H) equals the week we're in, it should color the full row and keep it like this.

I've achieved the full row with conditional formatting, but still remain with 2 problems. 
How to determine if this value in Column H is the same as the week we're in now? How do i keep my conditional formatting, so that when it is week 8 this row with week 7 remains coloured?

If conditional formatting is the wrong way to go, please tell me. I am learning, and would like to learn, not just a straight up answer how to fix my problem.

Comment: You can use the `WEEKNUM` function to get the week number, then just check `=WEEKNUM(H4+25, 2)=WEEKNUM(TODAY(), 2)`

Comment: Missed your second bit, `=WEEKNUM(H4+25, 2)<=WEEKNUM(TODAY(), 2)` with the less than or equal too.

Comment: Thank you Tim, that solved my problem without having to use the extra column. Perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `WEEKNUM` you can use the following:

```
=WEEKNUM(H4+25, 2)<=WEEKNUM(TODAY(), 2)
```

The `2` in WEEKNUM indicates which day of the week to take as the first, after 1st January (which is week 1)

Comment: As already said in comments above, thank you for your solution. Would like to correct you for one point (don't want to sound like a wise-ass or something), but the 2 is for when the week start with monday, as it starts with monday, i'm using a 1 for 2017.

as stated in below link:

https://support.office.com/nl-nl/article/WEEKNUMMER-functie-e5c43a03-b4ab-426c-b411-b18c13c75340

Comment: Its fine, however my statement above is exactly as the article says, the number 2 indicates which day of the week to take as the first, after the 1st of january which is week 1, so yes using a 1 makes it Sunday this year (and week 1), and a 2 makes it a monday, and week 2 :)

Comment: I see now. Excuse my n00b comment. Cheers for helping me out, Tim.

Comment: No not all, I didn't explain very well in the post.